# Jquery selector returns undefinded

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code for my input:

```
 <label for="search-term-id">

                <input type="text" class="search-term" placeholder="What are you looking for?"
                       id="search-term-id">

            </label>
```

And this is my class which I want when user types some text in the input , an alert message shows up:

```
import $ from 'jquery';


class Search {

    constructor() {

        console.log('Bundled!');
        this.openButton = $('.js-search-trigger');
        this.closeButton = $('.search-overlay__close');
        this.searchOverlay = $('.search-overlay');
        this.events();
        this.isOverlayOpen = false;
        this.searchField =$('#search-term-id');
    }


    events() {

        this.openButton.on('click', this.openOverlay.bind(this));
        this.closeButton.on('click', this.closeOverlay.bind(this));

        $(document).on('keydown', this.keyPressDispatcher.bind(this));
        this.searchField.on('keydown', this.typingLogic);
    }


    typingLogic () {
        alert('Hello from typingLogic');
    }

    keyPressDispatcher(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 83 && !this.isOverlayOpen) {
            this.openOverlay();
        }


        if(e.keyCode === 27 && this.isOverlayOpen) {

            this.closeOverlay();
        }
    }

    openOverlay() {
                this.searchOverlay.addClass('search-overlay--active');
                /* When we are seeing the overlay: */
                $('body').addClass('body-no-scroll');
                console.log('opening');
                this.isOverlayOpen = true;
    }
    closeOverlay() {   
            this.searchOverlay.removeClass('search-overlay--active');
            $('body').removeClass('body-no-scroll');
        this.isOverlayOpen = false;
        console.log('closing');
    }
}

export default Search;
```

But now the browser gives me an error that says:
"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined on:**" 
The line is :

```
this.searchField.on('keydown', this.typingLogic);
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Are you loading your JavaScript before the DOM is ready?

Comment: can  it be that you are firing `this.events();` in constructor before defining `this.searchField =$('#search-term-id');` ?

Comment: @lietutis Thank you! It works.I change my code in constructor() and insert `this.events();` after all of the codes in the constructor(). Would you write your comment as answer? To approve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In constructor there is `this.events();` which is called before `this.searchField` being set.

so to fix it put the `this.events();` as last line of constructor. which mean after `this.searchField =$('#search-term-id');` line.